# kineticjs - How to get points from a line

Tags: javascript, dom-events, kineticjs

If I create a line...

```
 var line = new Kinetic.Line({
  points: [0 , 5, 0, 100],
  stroke: 'black',
  strokeWidth: 2,
  draggable: true
```

});

And I attach a event...

```
   line.on("mouseup", function () {
      updateLineInput( this.attrs.points );
   });
```

How could I get the points back out? `this.attrs.points` does not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the points with `line.getPoints()` but they usually don't change after dragging and dropping, the X, Y coordinates change which the relative points are drawn from.  You can get those with `line.getX()` and `line.getY()`

```
  //It would be better to use the 'dragend' event if you want it to fire on a drag/drop
  line.on('dragend', function() {

    //You may really want the coordinates too
    var x = line.getX();
    var y = line.getY();

    //But this is what you asked for:
    var points = line.getPoints();
    updateLineInput(points);
  });
```

Comment: getX and getY was what I am after, but how do I get the x and y of the end of the line? I am guessing that that gives the x and y of the start position? or is that the offset?

Answer (score 1):

I concur with nak but I would recommend:

```
 //It would be better to use the 'dragend' event if you want it to fire on a drag/drop
  line.on('dragend', function(evt) {
     var myline=evt.shape;
    //You may really want the coordinates too
    var x = myline.getX();
    var y = myline.getY();

    //But this is what you asked for:
    var points = myline.getPoints();

    var mynewpoints=manipulate(points);
    myline.setPoints(mynewpoints);
    var mylayer=myline.getLayer();
    mylayer.draw();
  });
```